# Switch expression on System.Type in C# 8

Tags: c#, switch-statement, c#-8.0

I'm curious is any other way to write something like this with new switch expression in C# 8?

```cs
public static object Convert(string str, Type type) =>
    type switch
    {
        _ when type == typeof(string) => str,
        _ when type == typeof(string[]) => str.Split(new[] { ',', ';' }),
        _ => TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).ConvertFromString(str)
    };
```

Because `_ when type == typeof(string)` looks kinda weird especially when we have [type pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression#patterns-and-case-guards) and other very convenient instruments.

Comment: No, what you have is the only way I'm afraid.

Comment: Possibly move the typeof to assign to a static variable? Allowing something like `_ when type == stringType => str,` which may read _slightly_ better?

Comment: Have you considered using generics rather than returning `object`?

Comment: Unfortunately generic method is not suitable in my case

Comment: This does look like a peculiar method though, perhaps it is an XY problem and could be done in a completely different, but better, way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have alluded to, you actually need to have an *instance* of a type available to use the new type-matching features, not the representative `System.Type`.  If you want to match directly on the type, the way you're doing it seems to be the only viable way for the time being.

That being said, I would argue in this case that a standard `switch` statement might be more readable:

```
switch (type)
{
    case Type _ when type == typeof(string):
        return str;

    case Type _ when type == typeof(string[]):
        return str.Split(',', ';');

    default:
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).ConvertFromString(str);
}
```

If you *really* want to keep the switch expression, you could potentially get around this by matching on type names instead, though as a commenter pointed out below, this option is particularly brittle and will not work with certain types (such as `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>`):

```
public static object Convert(string str, Type type) =>
    type.Name switch
    {
        nameof(string) => str,
        nameof(string[]) => str.Split(new[] { ',', ';' }),
        _ => TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).ConvertFromString(str)
    };
```

Comment: Worth noting - this switching on type.name falls apart when you use nullable fields. e.g. datetime? will be 'nullable`'

Comment: Excellent point, I've updated my answer to reflect that caveat.

Answer (score 2):

If you would use generics and use the latest c# version you could do something like this:

```cs
public partial class DateMultiSelect<TDate> where TDate: struct
{
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if(default(TDate) switch 
        {
            DateOnly => true,
            DateTime => true,
            DateTimeOffset => true,
            _ => false
        })
            throw new ArgumentException($"TDate must be a date type, but is {typeof(TDate).Name}");

        base.OnParametersSet();
    }
}
```

according to your example this would be something along those lines:
(can be compiled, but didn't test it at runtime)

```cs
public static T? Convert<T>(string? str) =>
        default(T) switch
        {
            string => (T?)(dynamic?)str,
            string[] => (T?)(dynamic?)str?.Split(new[] { ',', ';' }),
            _ => (T?)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromString(str)
        };
```

instead of dynamic also object could be used.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation I ended up using a generic helper to make intent clearer. I did have `<T>` type available but not the C#9 `default (T) switch { string[] => ...}`  syntax.

This solution seems to be handling nullables like `DateTime?` correctly.

```cs
static object Convert(string str, Type type)
    => type switch {
        _ when Match<string>(type) => str,
        _ when Match<string[]>(type) => str.Split(new[] { ',', ';' }),
        _ => TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).ConvertFromString(str)
    };
static bool Match<T>(Type t) => typeof(T) == t;
```

For my `<T>` available case it became something like:

```cs
static object Convert<T>(string str)
    => type switch
    {
        _ when Match<string, T>() => str,
        _ when Match<string[], T>() => str.Split(new[] { ',', ';' }),
        _ => TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromString(str)
    };
static bool Match<TA, TB>() => typeof(TA) == typeof(TB);
```

**edit**:
One can shorten the syntax a bit with an extension method:

```cs
...
public static bool Is<T>(this System.Type type) => type == typeof(T);
...
static object Convert(string str, Type type)
    => type switch {
        _ when type.Is<string>() => str,
        _ when type.Is<string[]>() => str.Split(new[] { ',', ';' }),
        _ => TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).ConvertFromString(str)
    };
```